# how to get date format from locale

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently learning angular, and have a question dealing with the date time formats.
I am able to set the user locale to moment.js and set it globally and use moment.js to show the date/time.
But, I wanted to show the format of the locale in the placeholder of the date input. How can i do that?

Comment: `toLocaleString()` ?

Comment: this doesn't return the format, but the date in string. I want to get the format of the date in the locale, to be displayed in the placeholder

Comment: @Thernys, Yes, it may be a possible duplicate. I was able to solve my issue, by using 'var formatL = moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L')' I had not used the _moment-with-locales.min.js_ file as well. I included that and used the localeData and it worked!! Thanks a lot, to pointing it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question!

What you are looking for is `moment.localeData()` this call will return you a bunch of locale specific functionality. assume you are formatting using date-time formats `LT, L, LL` and so on. you will need the `longDateFormat` object

```
// assume you have set locale to be en-gb
localeData = moment.localeData()
localeData.longDateFormat()
```

this will return you

```
{
  LT : 'HH:mm',
  LTS : 'HH:mm:ss',
  L : 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  LL : 'D MMMM YYYY',
  LLL : 'D MMMM YYYY HH:mm',
  LLLL : 'dddd, D MMMM YYYY HH:mm'
}
```

here is the [doc](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/locale-data/)

Comment: Yes I was able to solve my issue, by using 'var formatL = moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L')' I had not used the moment-with-locales.min.js file as well. I included that and used the localeData and it worked!! @Thernys, pointed out the same stuff. Thanks

Comment: to whoever voted down, can you please tell me why this was a bad answer?

Comment: This was very useful to me. thanks

Comment: @ChampikaSamarasinghe thanks! I am glad I could help!