# How to get date format pattern string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular

I need the localized date format pattern string i.e. 'dd mmmm yyyy' or 'mmmm dd, yyyy'.

I need to pass this string to a external plugin that uses it for showing dates.

**Note: I do not need to format a date. I need to get the format "pattern string" of the user's locale.**

Comment: Maybe use to *toLocaleString()*   --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: @Maxim I do not need to format a date. I need to get the format "pattern string" of the user's locale.

Comment: @Tushar There are multiple ways to show the date in a format. BUT I do not want that. I want the user's locale date format string i.e. 'mmmm dd, yyyy' or something. And for that I haven't found any solution.

Comment: @Stackoverflow mods/police See Ben's answer below and read questions carefully before downvoting.

Comment: I'm still confused why not use your server side to handle the locale? For example in .NET framework it handles localisation very simple, I assume other server side language have similar functionality.

Comment: I have upvoted because I'm now solving similar problem... :) Have you handled that? And how?

Comment: @Frimlik I eventually used momentjs as there was no native approach possible without help of a library.

Answer (score 2):

It does not seem like it's possible to do this natively in JavaScript - you could either import a library like [Moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37037456/4186768) or you could use a static map from a resource such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9893752/4186768).

Comment: Thanks Elliot for confirming because I too was unable to find a way using native Javascript. 

Using a static map would be hardcoding and prone to errors. It seems like momentjs would be the best way to go. I will wait for other answers to see if there is a possible way in native javascript.